# ICollection object edit cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want create or edit in collection object. But collection object in return null controller .

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelEditManuscript
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string ArchiveNumber { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ViewModelEditManuscriptAuthor> Authors { get; set; 

}

public class ViewModelEditManuscriptAuthor
{
    public ViewModelEditPerson Author { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelEditPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TRName { get; set; }        
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModelEdit viewModelEdit)
{
    problem this.viewModel.Authors = null;
}
```

Cshtml:

```
foreach (var item in @Model.Entity.Authors)                          
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Author.Id)                          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use  `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Author.Id)` inside your loop, For all  textboxes inside the loop, It is going to generate textbox markup with name property as

```
name="item.Author.Id"
```

When the form is submitted the Modelbinder cannot map this form data to an object of the `ViewModelEditManuscript` class.

For the model binding to work, you need to make sure that you are generating the proper field names which matches with your view model property hierarchy.

Since our `ViewModelEditManuscript` class has a collection property called `Authors` and each item of that again has an `Author` property which again has an `Id` property, We should tell razor to generate `name` value for our inputs like

```
name="Authors[0].Author.Id"  
name="Authors[1].Author.Id"
```

We can do `Html.TextBox` helper method to do that. The first parameter is the value for the name property of the input.

```
@model ViewModelEditManuscript
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in @Model.Authors)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("Authors[" + i+ "].Author.Id",item.Author.Id)

        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

This will work assuming your HttpPost action method's argument is of type `ViewModelEditManuscript`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WhateverYourActionMethodNameIs(ViewModelEditManuscript model)
{
   // do something with model and redirect/return something            
}
```

Comment: I want to new Authors but new textbox not created in jquery

Comment: Sorry ! I do not understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
I wantto Authors save.

//this Domain
 public class Manuscript 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ArchiveNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ManuscriptAuthor> Authors { get; set; }
}

  public class ManuscriptAuthor
    {
        public int ManuscriptId { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    }

//this controller
 public ActionResult Edit(ViewModelEdit viewModelEdit)
 {
     Manuscript manuscript = null;
     manuscript.Authors = viewModelEdit.Entity.Authors; // this  error
 }
```